# How can i make "checkboxes" that increase their number at each left click and decrease at right click?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm currently using a form with imaged checkboxes :

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">  
<table cellspacing="15">
<tr>
<td>
  <label for="lightning"><img src="units/lightning.png"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lightning" id="lightning">
</td>
<td>
  <label for="delita"><img src="units/delita.png"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="delita" id="delita">
</td>
<td>
```

(it goes further down for a while, didn't paste everything)

it's a basic checkbox, but what i want is something that stacks numbers the more you click. For exemple, let's say i click once on the checkbox with my left click : it will check it and a "1" will appear above. If two times, a 2 etc...and with the right click it would decrease that said number. Is it possible in any form?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Checkboxes are not counters. They're either checked or not. And *while I'm at it, here's a totally different question* isn't acceptable. When you created your account here, it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. Please do so, especially [ask].

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, i edited my post. What is the correct html code/use for what i'm looking please?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad.  Checkboxes are not suitable for this task, and this is not something that can be done in simple HTML without some sort of JavaScript, since there must be logic which would keep track of the counter that would be displayed.

Comment: @Claies I understand, i was hoping for a page where users could manually select multiple counters and set them at the values they wanted (for personnal use) and register it in the database. If this cannot be done by simple mean, i will drop it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What about an HTML spinner control instead?

Comment: @Claies Hello, what does a HTML spinner control do? For more info just in case, i made a gif of the exact concept i'm looking for : https://i.imgur.com/AxbDcyA.gif

Comment: You need 2 checkboxes and javascript one to count up and one to count down.

Comment: You could use buttons, links, not just checkboxes You have to have 2 of whatever you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something similar to what you asked.. as other said, checkboxes should not be used for this kind of things.. anyway you can take it like an example: (using jQuery)

```js
$('#myform input[type="checkbox"]').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $numberElem = $(this).parent().find('.number');
    var num = $numberElem.html();
    if(e.which == 1){  // left click
        num++;
    }
    else if(e.which == 3){  // right click
        num--;
    }
    $numberElem.html(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myform">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="number">0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="number">0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```